# Creación continua de archivos de texto en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo mi código en javascript que me crea un archivo de texto con el contenido del directorio, pero quisiera que me cree uno detrás del otro y no sobrescribirlos. ¿Hay alguna manera?

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

function fileFunc() {
  exec('ls > hello.txt', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
  });
}

setInterval(fileFunc, 5000);
clearInterval(fileFunc);
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es que se genere un solo archivo y dentro del mismo, al final se agregen lineas de texto? o Quieres crear archivos diferentes?

Comment: Quiero que me haga el hello1.txt,, hello2.txt, hello3.txt y asi sucesivamente hasta detener el script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando `Backticks`.

```javascript
const { exec } = require('child_process');

function fileFunc(i) {
    
  exec(`ls > hello.txt${i}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
  });

}

let i=0; 

setInterval(() => {
    fileFunc(i)
    i++
}, 5000);

clearInterval(fileFunc);
})
```

De esta forma siempre vas a generar un documento con un número irrepetible y por tanto no sobrescribirás tus archivos .txt.

> Fuente: https://betterprogramming.pub/javascript-how-backticks-work-de269e0fb8ba

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, eso era justamente lo que necesitaba.